# Veracrypt rescue disk doesnt work

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader, veracrypt

After completing an FDE with veracrypt on my laptop, a restart lead to windows automatic repair. During the encryption process, veracrypz required me to save a rescue image on a usb disk, consisting of a folder called EFI i needed to copy to the stick. 
Booting from the stick leads to the message "OS not found", booting from a cd i burned the folder on results in the same auto-repair. i have the correct boot order.

how can i get the rescue image loaded or recover my laptop with other means?

Comment: Does the stick contain just the EFI folder, or did you add that to the rescue image?

Comment: it contains just the efi folder

Comment: i thought that the folder is the rescue image

Comment: No, that's just to boot.  You need to add that to the rescue disk.  The rescue disk should contain the OS and rescue files.

Comment: where can i download the rescue disk?

Comment: "During the encryption process, veracrypz required me to save a rescue image on a usb disk".  The rescue image is typically created from what's on your system, or is stored in a partition by the computer OEM as part of the Windows installation.  See if you can find a Recovery partition on the hard drive.

Comment: Exactly, it created a zip file with the efi folder as content. Thats all